# Django Как заполнить БД данными из внешнего api?

Tags: python, django

Создал приложение - mysite
Внутри него создал модель Cars с полем id

```
class Cars(models.Model):
idx = models.CharField('ID', max_length=10)
```

В этом же приложении добавил файл api.py

В котором получил и преобразовал в  список словарей данные

Пример

```
[{'id': '1', 'number': '1'},{'id': '2', 'number': '2'}]
```

Есть два вопроса.

1. Как данными из этого файла заполнить БД
2. Как создать в админке кнопку, для запуска этого скрипта?

Comment: добавьте код модели Cars и содержимое "в List данные"?

Comment: Вопрос импровизированный. В модели только одно поле id
Ну и массив объектов. В каждом объекте есть ключ id.